# How to get the id of commit using JavaGit library?

Tags: java, git

I use this code from the [JavaGit example](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/cookbook.php#h):

```
File repositoryDirectory = new File("Library\\build\\jar\\");
    DotGit dotGit = DotGit.getInstance(repositoryDirectory);

    // Print commit messages of the current branch
    for (Commit c : dotGit.getLog()) {
        System.out.println(c.getMessage());
    }
```

How could I get the id of commit this way?
Or it might be more appropriate library to interact with git?

Comment: Just to let you know [I've forked JavaGit](https://github.com/bit-man/SwissArmyJavaGit), solved some bugs and added some enhancements.

BTW no changes to he documentation yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/docs/javagit-0.1.0-javadoc/edu/nyu/cs/javagit/api/Commit.html) (I don't know very much this library), you should invoke the `getCommitName()` method and use the returned `Ref` object to get the information you want (I think the SHA1 hash or the tag).

Comment: So strange that documentation contains better information than code examples. You'd almost think it is a good idea to read it.

Comment: @Gimby Yeah. In theory, the documentation should be always complete and concise. In practice, most of the times, it isn't. It's nice sometimes that there's an exception. :-)